# How to allow only one decimal point for input of type number in ionic 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex, ionic-framework

I am using a input of type number in which it allows multiple decimal points so i have tried using the regex not to allow more than one decimal point but even after using the regex i am facing the same issue can anyone tell me how to allow only one decimal point in input of type number in ionic1

Html:

```
<input stopccp focus-me class="inputContainer trade_input" type="number" name="" ng-model="vm.total_amount[$index]" ng-change="vm.onTotalCost()" limit-char limit="5" ng-keyup="vm.decimalcheck(vm.total_amount[$index])"  >
```

Regex in function:

```
function decimalcheck (element) {
  $log.log('decimalcheck got called', element);
  var regex = /\d*\.?\d?/g;
  return regex.exec(element);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LkaogG/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of String
- `\d*`- 0+ digits
- `\.?`- 0 or 1 decimal point
- `\d+`- 1+ digits(thus making it mandatory to have atleast one digit after the decimal point, if it is present)
- `$`- End of String

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d+\.?\d?(?!\d)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Script**

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 1) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 1)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }      
});

$('.number').bind("paste", function(e) {
var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
if ($.isNumeric(text)) {
    if ((text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 3) && (text.indexOf('.') > -1)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(text.substring(0, text.indexOf('.') + 3));
   }
}
else {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="number" />
```

[Here is your answer](https://jsfiddle.net/fb2pqsmo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just miss start(^) and end($) operator

```
function decimalcheck (element) {
  $log.log('decimalcheck got called', element);
  var regex = /^\d*\.?\d?$/g;
  return regex.exec(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your html, It worked for me

```
pattern = "^\d*\.?\d+$"
```

like this:

```
<input stopccp focus-me class="inputContainer trade_input" type="number" name="" ng-model="vm.total_amount[$index]" ng-change="vm.onTotalCost()" limit-char limit="5" ng-keyup="vm.decimalcheck(vm.total_amount[$index])" pattern="^\d*\.?\d+$">
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer

Comment: I apologize for the unintentional duplicate answer. Your observation is valid, and I appreciate your understanding." @Tom

Answer (score 0):

this work with input field use pattern and event onInput

```
<input
   maxLength={4}
   type="text"
   pattern="\d+\.?\d?(?!\d)" // [0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
   value={unitProgress}
   onInput={(e: any) => {
      const valueChange = e.target.validity.valid 
                             ? e.target.value 
                             : unitProgress;
      setUnitProgress(valueChange);

  }}
                                       
/>
```

Comment: library use with reactjs